# Not all code paths return a value // Returns void

Tags: c#, arrays, object, return-value, quicksort

I am trying to implement a quickSort of an Array ( a file ) but in doing so i get 2 errors. I will comment them down in the code.

```
    static int[] quick(int[] array, int start, int end)
   // 'quick(int[], int, int)': Not all code paths return a value (i have tried to return this.)
        {
            int i3;
            if (start < end)
            {
                i3 = Partition(array, start, end);

                quick(array, start, i3 - 1);
                quick(array, i3 + 1, end);
            }
        }

        static int Partition(int[] array, int start, int end)
        {
            int temp;
            int p = array[end];
            int i3 = start - 1;

            for (int j = start; j <= end - 1; j++)
            {
                if (array[j] <= p)
                {
                    i3++;
                    temp = array[i3];
                    array[i3] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;
                }
            }

            temp = array[i3 + 1];
            array[i3 + 1] = array[end];
            array[end] = temp;
            return i3 + 1;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The file sorted via a Quick Sort is: ");
        foreach (int q1 in f)
            Console.Write(q1 + " ");
        return quick;
    // Since 'Program.Main(string[])' returns void, a returner keyword must not be followed by an object expression..
    }
```

I am fairly new to C# and don't understand these errors, when I change the Main to an object nothing changes, hope this makes sense , all help appreciated.

Comment: You define `quick` as returning a `int[]`, but you don't actually return anything from the method.  It looks like that method should be `void` instead.  We need to see more of the code for the other error, but it looks like the code after the `Partition` method is not actually contained in a method, but if it's actually in a `void Main` then you should not actually return anything.

Comment: @juharr I see , I have now put the Partition method within the quick method and when trying to return quick (the file that will be analysed) - get 1) "Cannot convert method group 'quick' to type 'int[]' " AND 2) "Static local function cannot contain a reference"